# Chapel : Understanding lifetime of managed classes with zip and user-defined iterators

Tags: object-lifetime, chapel

I'm trying to understand the lifetime of an `owned` class, when being used in a user-defined iterator.  Consider the following code :

```
var a = new owned C();
var b = new owned C();
a.i = 2;

forall (a1,b1) in zip(a,b) {
  b1 = a1;
}

forall (a1,b1) in zip(a,b) {
  writeln(a1, " ",b1);
}

class C {
  var i : int;
  iter these() {
    yield 1;
  }

  iter these(param tag : iterKind) where tag==iterKind.leader {
    yield 1;
  }

  iter these(param tag : iterKind, followThis) ref
  where tag==iterKind.follower {
    yield i;
  }
}
```

Compiling and running this code gives the following error

```
(08:54)$ chpl test.chpl --warn-unstable
(08:54)$ ./test
test.chpl:25: error: attempt to dereference nil
(08:54)$ chpl --version
chpl version 1.19.0 pre-release (2c10dbe)
```

It isn't clear to me when the class is being `deinit`-ed here. If I replace the `owned` with a `shared`, this example works as expected. More interestingly, changing the first loop to

```
forall (a1,b1) in zip(a.borrow(),b.borrow()) {
```

allows the code to work as well. In what cases is an argument automatically coerced into a `borrowed` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug. I'll have a look.

> In what cases is an argument automatically coerced into a borrowed instance?

Right now, when:

1. when calling a method on it (the `this` argument will be a borrow)
2. when passing to an argument of type `C` or `borrowed C` (which mean the same).
3. when passing to a totally generic function argument.

I'm not sure if we're going to keep rule 3 or not. But that's not the problem in your case - rather the problem is that some compiler-introduced code implementing the forall statement taking away the `owned` value. That's a bug.

Comment: The bug should now be fixed on Chapel master and I expect the fix to be available in Chapel 1.19.

Comment: And I can confirm that this works for me! Thanks for that very quick fix!